# How to Zip folder with AppleScript-objc?

Tags: applescript-objc

I'm generating a few Logs on the system, and then copying it to /tmp/MyFolder, and then 
I move the folder to the desktop, I'm trying to compact it before you move on, but I don't know how to do it, I have tried the following:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theItem to "/tmp/MyFolder" as alias
    set itemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of theItem
    set fileName to name of theItem
    set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of theItem as alias)
    set zipFile to quoted form of (theFolder & fileName & ".zip")
    do shell script "zip -r " & zipFile & " " & itemPath
end tell
```

Comment: @CJK I want to create a small APP with this feature.

Comment: @CJK,  What I'm doing is creating a button and when this button is clicked it generates a folder in / tmp with system logs and then copies this folder to desktop, what I wanted is that it was already copied to the desktop such as a zipped folder.

Comment: Yes I would like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't an AppleScript-ObjC script, I'm posting the corrected version of your own script so that it functions to do as you described:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set itemPath to "/tmp/MyFolder"
    set theItem to item itemPath
    set fileName to quoted form of (get name of theItem)
    set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of theItem)
    set zipFile to fileName & ".zip"
end tell

do shell script "cd " & quoted form of theFolder & ¬
    "; zip -r " & zipFile & space & fileName & ¬
    "; mv " & zipFile & space & "~/Desktop/"
```

Trying to avoid using *Finder* for file system operations.  It sounds counter-intuitive, but it's not well-suited for it.  Use *System Events*, which has—among many other benefits—the ability to handle posix paths.

The script now zips the folder and its containing items into an archive at `/tmp/MyFolder.zip`, then moves this archive to the desktop.

Comment: Error: System Events got an error: Can’t get item "/tmp/System\\ Logs"

Comment: That means you've altered the script as there is no reference to `/tmp/System Logs` in your original script or mine.  Please tell me exactly what you've edited.

Comment: I've just noticed the backslashes in the error message.  I'm assuming you `set itemPath to "/tmp/System\\ Logs"`...?  If so, you've created an invalid path and file reference because of the backslashes.  The path name is a quoted string, not a command-line argument, so you shouldn't escape spaces.  Remove the backslashes and try again.

Comment: Error: mv: rename System Logs.zip to /Users/theiamtheonlyonehere/Desktop/System Logs.zip: No such file or directory